# How to run train/test command for "Pix2Pix" code on "Floydhub" using my own data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dcgan, floydhub

I'm trying to run [Pix2Pix-tensorflow](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow) on Floydhub using my own data.

I have organised my datafolder as mentioned in the Pix2Pix documentation. The datafolder contains 3 folders: train, test, val.

I attempted to run the following train command on floydhub command line:

```
floyd run --gpu --data zaalee/datasets/tablesdata/2:/my_data "python pix2pix.py --mode train --output_dir /output --max_epochs 200 --input_dir /my_data --which_direction AtoB"
```

However after running the job for a few seconds, the job Fails, and I get the following error:

```
2019-03-24 20:25:46,420 INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):

2019-03-24 20:25:46,420 INFO - File "pix2pix.py", line 803, in <module>

2019-03-24 20:25:46,420 INFO - main()

2019-03-24 20:25:46,420 INFO - File "pix2pix.py", line 625, in main

2019-03-24 20:25:46,421 INFO - examples = load_examples()

2019-03-24 20:25:46,421 INFO - File "pix2pix.py", line 244, in load_examples

2019-03-24 20:25:46,421 INFO - raise Exception("input_dir contains no image files")

2019-03-24 20:25:46,421 INFO - Exception: input_dir contains no image files

2019-03-24 20:25:50,680 INFO -
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my mistake.

The correct command is -

```
floyd run --gpu --data zaalee/datasets/tablesdata/2:/my_data "python pix2pix.py --mode train --output_dir /output --max_epochs 200 --input_dir /my_data/train --which_direction AtoB"
```

The "train" folder needs to be added after `my_data` folder like so 
`--input_dir /my_data/train`